# How to determine if user has shared a link in Google+ or not?

Tags: google-plus

I need to provide download of a file, if user shares my site with his google+ account. How can I achieve this using Google API.

For example -

I have a PDF file (learning document) that I want to share.
The condition is if you want to get that file you have to share my link to your google+ account.
The code will verify if its already posted to your account and will allow you to download the PDF file.

Is there any solution for this in Google+ like Facebook does?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. Can you edit your question to elaborate and describe exactly the steps you expect someone to take, and the part where you're having problems?

Comment: If you can elaborate, that would be very helpful.  It is important to remember, though, that you may not provide that file as an incentive for a user sharing/promoting your site.  For guidelines on using the Share button, please review our Buttons Policy at https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/buttons-policy.